# Split cofiber sequence

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $A \rightarrow X \rightarrow X/A $ be a cofiber sequence (inclusion of $A$ in $X$ is a cofibration), where $A$ is a retract of $X$. Then $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $A \vee X/A$. How can one see it?

Comment: That doesn't seem right, consider the map $ S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \vee S^1 $

Comment: I think if you want an analogy with something like split exact sequence of abelian groups, you want to claim that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $A \vee X/A$. But, this isn't true either: consider the inclusion $S^1 \to S^2$ thinking of $S^1$ as the equator of $S^2$. Then the cofiber sequence is $S^1 \to S^2 \to S^2 \vee S^2$ since pinching the equator of $S^2$ gives a wedge sum of two 2-spheres. But, of course, $S^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^2 \vee S^2$.

Comment: @SiddharthGurumurthy sorry for the typo... I meant wedge

Comment: @kamills S^1 is not a retract of S^2

Comment: Still not convinced, consider the map $ S^1 \times I \rightarrow T^2 $, where it's the inclusion of half of the torus into the entire torus. The quotient should be a pinched torus, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^2$.

Comment: Siddharth Gurumurthy and his example are correct. One cannot see it because it is not true. Perhaps you mean to work in the stable category?

Comment: I guess I had further typos... I meant a homology isomorphism...

Comment: @Anupam oops! Missed the retraction hypothesis when I read the question. Certainly you'll have isomorphic homology groups since the long exact sequence for the cofibration will break up into split short exact sequences using the retraction. But you in general cannot claim that there's a continuous map inducing this isomorphism, and you can see this using Siddharth's example: if there were, it'd give a cohomolgy ring isomorphism, but the cup product structure on $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ is trivial whereas on $S^1 \times S^1$ it's not.